Error: Cannot establish one or more browser connections
Whenever I run my test scripts in GuidewireTestingFramework, the browser launches and the scripts execute successfully. Suddenly since yesterday , the browser is not launching and my script fails with the below error.
Command used for running script> npm run gt-tests --cucumberTags='@smoketest' 
I am using gradle project and nodejs 18.20.3.
Version in package.json--
"testcafe": "3.10.0"
"gherkin-testcafe": "7.1.2"
Hints:

Increase the Browser Initialization Timeout if its value is too low (currently: 2 minutes for all browsers). The timeout determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.

The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.

at new BrowserConnectionError (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\testcafe\src\errors\runtime\index.js:196:9)
at BrowserSet.createBrowserConnectionError (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:126:16)
at Function.from (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:108:30) 
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at Bootstrapper._bootstrapParallel (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:389:38) 
at Bootstrapper.createRunnableConfiguration (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\test.cafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:413:25)
at GherkinTestcafeRunner._getRunTaskOptions (C:\Users\XX\guidewiretestingframework_R2\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\index.js:596:75


I tried the below things:

Increased the browserInitTimeout, but that did not work. It was getting timed-out with whatever value is increased
The network is absolutely fine too.
Headless mode is also throwing the same error.
Facing the issue in my local PC.

I am expecting the browser to launch (with or without headless) and successfully navigate to the URL. Kindly suggest
